# In Swift, for AnyObject, how do I setValue() then call valueForKey()

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I'd like to store a value in AnyObject then retrieve it later as follows:

```
var obj:AnyObject = UIButton()
obj.setValue("James", forKey: "owner")
obj.valueForKey("owner")
```

However, AnyObject does not allow it even if these methods are available as shown by the error:

```
setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key owner.'
```

How could this be done?

Comment: Neither UIButton nor AnyObject has a property `owner`, so what are you expecting here?

Comment: @matt, "owner" is just any user defined key.  Main question is how to use .setValue and .valueForKey methods which are available (compiles) for AnyObject?

Comment: You are using them just fine. That's why your app compiles. But when your app runs, that's when it turns out that there is no such key. As I say in my answer below, there are no "user-defined keys" for a UIButton or an AnyObject.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot assign to an arbitrary key of a UIButton. Some classes do permit this (CALayer and CAAnimation come to mind, and NSDictionary of course), but neither UIButton nor AnyObject is such a class, and neither has an `owner` property — so trying to set it is nonsense, and that is what causes the crash at runtime. You can set a button's *existing* property using a key, but you can't just invent your own key like this.

Comment: Are runtime object associations easy to get at from Swift?

Comment: @Tommy No. In most languages they are pretty hard to get because the memory layout of an object is fixed. The functionality is rarely needed though because it requires accessing a property dynamically (using its name) and there are much simpler way to achieve the same, e.g. encapsulation, inheritance or a separate dictionary. Swift is not javascript.

Comment: @Tommy What is it that you are _really_ trying to do? There's probably a much simpler way... It seems to me you've asked the wrong question - you've _assumed_ a way of accomplishing your goal rather than asking _how_ to accomplish that goal.

Comment: Not my question; all I was _really_ trying to do was take an opportunity to learn about Swift's access, if any, to another of the Objective-C runtime features. I've not had much of an opportunity to use Swift yet.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused about who is who.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot just add properties to objects dynamically. That's not how Swift works. You could get away with it in Javascript (and a bit in Obj-C) but not in Swift.

There are several simple ways out of your problem:

1. Encapsulation - create a class encapsulating a button and its owner, e.g. `OwnedButton`.
2. Inheritance - Override UIButton, adding it a new `owner` property. Then you will be able to just set `button.owner = ...`.
3. Let the owner save the buttons it owns `owner.addButton(button)`
4. Save the relation separately, e.g. using a button-owner dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your buttons, you can create array of objects that can be stored.  See use of NSCoding below.

Class where I define objects - example from a game I wrote:

```
import Foundation

class ButtonStates: NSObject {

    var sign: String = "+"
    var level: Int = 1
    var problems: Int = 10
    var time: Int = 30
    var skipWrongAnswers = true

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder!) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(sign, forKey: "sign")
        aCoder.encodeInteger(level, forKey: "level")
        aCoder.encodeInteger(problems, forKey: "problems")
        aCoder.encodeInteger(time, forKey: "time")
        aCoder.encodeBool(skipWrongAnswers, forKey: "skipWrongAnswers")
    }

    init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
        sign = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("sign") as String
        level = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("level")
        problems = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("problems")
        time = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey("time")
        skipWrongAnswers = aDecoder.decodeBoolForKey("skipWrongAnswers")
    }

    override init() {
    }
}
```

Class where I archive and retrieve these objects:

```
import Foundation

class ArchiveButtonStates:NSObject {

    var documentDirectories:NSArray = []
    var documentDirectory:String = ""
    var path:String = ""

    func ArchiveButtons(#buttonStates: ButtonStates) {
        documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        documentDirectory = documentDirectories.objectAtIndex(0) as String
        path = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("buttonStates.archive")

        if NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(buttonStates, toFile: path) {
            //println("Success writing to file!")
        } else {
            println("Unable to write to file!")
        }
    }

    func RetrieveButtons() -> NSObject {
        var dataToRetrieve = ButtonStates()
        documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)
        documentDirectory = documentDirectories.objectAtIndex(0) as String
        path = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("buttonStates.archive")
        if let dataToRetrieve2 = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(path) as? ButtonStates {
            dataToRetrieve = dataToRetrieve2 as ButtonStates
        }
        return(dataToRetrieve)
    }
}
```

example of retrieving the data from a ViewController:

```
let buttonStates = ArchiveButtonStates().RetrieveButtons() as ButtonStates
```

example of storing data from a ViewController:

```
ArchiveGameData().ArchiveResults(dataSet: gameDataArray)
```

Answer (score -2):

`UIButton`, `-[NSObject setValue:forKey:]` and `-[NSObject valueForKey:]` are Objective-C Cocoa APIs. So your code does not work for the exact same reason that the corresponding Objective-C code does not work:

```
id obj = [[UIButton alloc] init];
[obj setValue:@"James" forKey:@"owner"];
[obj valueForKey:@"owner"];
```

Once you figure that out, you will have figured out the problem with your code.