# UIButton this class is not key value code-compliant for the key

Tags: ios, uibutton, storyboard

I have the following line of code:

```
[self.someBtn setValue:@"some-value" forKey:@"some-key"];
```

where `someBtn` is bind from storyboard. 
The problem is I get this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIButton 0x137e7deb0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key some-key.'
```

If I comment this line of code it works. I want just to pass some "meta" information through the UIButton by using setValue:forKey function.

Can somebody explain to me what is happening? Thank you!

Comment: "I want just to pass some "meta" information through the UIButton" - why? What are you trying to achieve? There is a better way to achieve what you're trying to do.

Comment: this issue is related with iboutlet please check your button iboutlet

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: The error message says the key (or property) `error-type` is not available. Maybe it's private.

Comment: which kind data you need to pass ?

Comment: @vadian error-type was initially the key, i'll update the question. instead of "error-type" consider "some-key"

Comment: @DeepakSaki I already checked and redone the bindings between storyboard and the uiviewcontroller class

Comment: Simple fact: If you use KVC and this error occurs, the key is not available and there is no workaround.

Comment: @mag_zbc  I just want to attach some information to the button. I'm aware that what I'm trying to do can be solved in many ways but I'm trying to do it using setValueforKey. I'm not searching for other methods, just trying to figure out why it crashes with that error.

Comment: @vadian it doesn't crash when I try to get the value by key. It crashes when I set the value/key

Comment: Then the property is read-only.

Comment: @vadian setValue forKey is a function and cannot be read-only. is a setter that sets/writes

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Swift, for AnyObject, how do I setValue() then call valueForKey()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667380/in-swift-for-anyobject-how-do-i-setvalue-then-call-valueforkey)

Comment: `setValue forKey` is a generic **Key-Value Coding** method which allows access to the property setter and getter by key. If the setter fails the underlying property is read-only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest to "attach some value to the button" via associated objects. You can write an extension for `UIButton` that does just that

```
@interface UIButton (AssociatedObject)

@property (nonatomic, strong) id associatedObject;

@end

@implementation UIButton (AssociatedObject)
@dynamic associatedObject;

- (void)setAssociatedObject:(id)object {
     objc_setAssociatedObject(self, @selector(associatedObject), object, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
}

- (id)associatedObject {
    return objc_getAssociatedObject(self, @selector(associatedObject));
}
```

You can read a [very good article on NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/associated-objects/) covering use of associated objects.

Please note that whatever you're trying to actually do, can probably be done much more easily by subclassing the button or storing the value somewhere else.

Comment: and for a complete answer: UIButtons are key-value compliant while, for ex., UIViews are not key-value compliant on generic keys, therefore setting custom key/value is not permited for UIButtons. In my case the UIButton does not have any property with the name "some-key".

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass any information with UIButton. You can only set int as a tag in your UIButton like this-

```
self.someBtn.tag = 1;
```

Comment: I would like to use setValueforKey, but thanks for the answer