# setValue:forKey is always crashing in swift

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, crash, key-value-coding

I have below use case:

```
class Foo: NSObject {
    var bar = ""
}

let foo = Foo()
foo.setValue("A name", forKey: "bar") //throws exception: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key bar.
print("Foo.bar: \(foo.bar)")
```

Apple documentation ([here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/)) sais that in Swift each class subclasing NSObject becomes by default key value compliant. If so why am I getting not key value compliant exception?

> Swift objects that inherit from NSObject or one of its subclasses are key-value coding compliant for their properties by default.

Am I missing something? Dose any one know which could be the problem?

Note: I tried to make the "bar" property NSString but i got the same exception.

Comment: This is answered. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667380/in-swift-for-anyobject-how-do-i-setvalue-then-call-valueforkey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To implement KVC(Key-Value Coding) support for a property.
you need the **@objc** annotation on your property, 
Since the current implementation of KVC is written in Objective-C, After adding **@objc**, Objective-c can see it.

```
class Foo: NSObject {
    @objc var bar = ""
}
let foo = Foo()
foo.setValue("A name", forKey: "bar")
print("Foo.bar: \(foo.bar)")
```